# Arg.Do() is not firing when expected in a When..Do for void method

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

I have the below structure in a test of mine, intended to test that a certain log is being called with the right complex argument object, even when it throws an exception which is then wrapped and generally manipulated further.
The logThing has a method:

```
void AddEntry(LogEntry);
```

So I am using When..Do to make it throw an exception,

```
public void UnitTest()
{
    // Arrange
    ILogThing logThing = Substitute.For<ILogThing>()
    SystemUnderTest system = new SystemUnderTest(logThing);

    List<LogEntry> actualEntries = new List<LogEntry>();
    LogEntry expectedEntry = GetSomeTestData();

    logThing.When(
        lt => lt.AddEntry(Arg.Do<LogEntry>(r => actualEntries.Add(r)))).Do(
        call => { throw new InvalidOperationException("testMessage"); });

    // Act
    try
    {
        system.DoSomethingWhichLogs(someArgs)
    }
    catch(WrappedException ex)
    {
        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(1, actualEntries.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(actualEntries[0], expectedEntry);
    }
}
```

However, the expected call to Arg.Do() never happens with this setup.

I have put a breakpoint in the catch block, and used Visual Studio's immediate window to call RecievedCalls<>() on the logThing, and it does have a record of a single call to logThing with the right arguments - it's just that Arg.Do appears to only execute after the When..Do block has finished. Clearly that means that since I am throwing in the When..Do, it never reaches it.

I really didn't expect NSubstitute to order the calls in this way, is that expected behaviour? 
If so, is there anything I can do to test the incoming argument like this, or should I just put my argument checking into the main When..Do block (which makes it harder to read)?

The system under test does various things to the exception which include wrapping it together with the logEntry, so it -is- useful for me to have all of these checks in one test - I did think about splitting it into two separate tests, but realized that if I did that, I couldn't easily pin down where the incorrect wrapped output was coming from (it could either be the part that originally generates the logEntry, or the part wrapping it) wheras with this pattern I can check to make sure the logThing is receiving what I expect it to. Still, if there's a better way to do that, I'm certainly open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact order of When..Do and Arg.Do isn't defined, and I wouldn't recommend counting on it as I imagine it could change between versions depending on implementation. (If you have a good reason to define it in a particular order please post your suggestion to the [usergroup](http://groups.google.com/group/nsubstitute).)

If you just want to check logThing received the expected LogEntry, you can check the argument after the fact using Arg.Is():

```
logThing.Received().AddEntry(Arg.Is(expectedEntry));
```

If you need more complex comparison logic, you can do the same thing but use a method to check the argument:

```
logThing.Received().AddEntry(Arg.Is<LogEntry>(x => CheckLogEntry(x)));
```

`CheckLogEntry` can do whatever checks you require, and you can keep the When..Do throwing as before.

If you need to use the When..Do approach, you can can keep your existing approach but move the capture of the argument into the `Do` call to ensure the order of calls that you expect:

```
logThing.When(
    lt => lt.AddEntry(Arg.Any<LogEntry>())).Do(
    call =>
    {
        actualEntries.Add(call.Arg<LogEntry>());
        throw new InvalidOperationException("testMessage");
    });
```

In terms of suggestions for other ways of testing this, I'm not entirely clear on what you are trying to do here, but if you are having trouble isolating where the wrapped output is coming from maybe you could move this responsibility to another dependency? This would let you substitute for this dependency and control exactly where this happened from the perspective of this test.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the ordering (or lack of). I don't have any solid reasons for wanting it this way, just that I expected it to happen 'before' the function the arguments are used for.

Originally, I had 
    logThing.Received().AddEntry(Arg.Do<LogEntry>(x => CheckLogEntry(x)));
but that didn't ever trigger. I hadn't actually thought about using .Is, but I'll do that with it returning a bool after the checks, I think that's the neatest way.

Comment: Yes, Arg.Do won't trigger in a Received(), as Received() is checking calls after the fact. Arg.Do only fires for future calls that are received.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to prevent .Is() from swallowing exceptions? It makes reading the assert from the error message basically impossible, as the currently thrown error from Is only says the complex object does not match, it doesn't specify where or how.

Comment: No, you can't stop Is swallowing exceptions. I wouldn't assert from the method you pass to Is, just return true or false based on whether it matches. We are currently working on implementing custom matchers that will provide more information, but that work hasn't hit the latest builds yet.

Comment: I've fallen back to capturing the argument for now - I need to know where in the object the issue is. I'll make sure to keep checking the later builds for that then.

Comment: Sounds good. Sorry for the inconvenience. Builds are on the CI server linked to on the website, and releases are announced on the usergroup (linked to in my answer), and also on Twitter (https://twitter.com/nsubstitute) if you find the list chatter too much.