# How can I redirect arguments using NSubstitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I am in the process of converting some test objects from RhinoMocks to NSubstitute and am having trouble setting up my mock repository.

See the following unit test code below:

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    _converter = Substitute.For<IStatisticsConverter>();
    _repository = Substitute.For<IRepository>();
    _updater = new StatisticsUpdater(_converter, null, _repository);
}

[Test]
public void CreateFrom_NoExistingItem_NewItemWithStatistics()
{
        var statisticsLog = new StatisticsLog();
        var statistics = new Statistics();

        _converter.ConvertToStatistics(statisticsLog).Returns(statistics);

        _repository.When(x => x.SaveStatistics(Arg.Any<Item>(), statistics))
            .Do(x => UpdateItem(?????,statistics));

        var actualItem = _updater.CreateFrom(statisticsLog);

        Assert.IsNotNull(actualItem);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, actualItem.Statistics.Count(), "number of statistics entries");
        Assert.AreSame(statistics, actualItem.Statistics.First(), "expected statistics");
}

private void UpdateItem(Item item, Statistics statistics)
{  
    item.AddStatistics(statistics);   
}
```

The test throws an error at `Assert.AreEqual`: "Expected 1 and Actual is 0."

What happens is, `_updater` is the System Under Test. The `CreateFrom()` function creates a new `Item()` and then internally calls `Update(statisticsLog)`. `StatisticsLog` is an XML file.

```
public Item CreateFrom(T deserializedEntity)
{
    Item = new Item();

    Update(deserializedEntity);

    return Item;
}
```

Once the file is parsed in the real updater, it gets saved to a database which is attached to the new `Item` (which was also added to the database as it did not exist before).

Now, the problem is, I need to get this newed `Item` and pass it into `UpdateItem()` which mocks the functionality of adding to the database. It adds the `Statistics` to the `Item.Statistics` list.

So - is there a way I can pull out this argument from the mocked `Repository` and pass it into `UpdateItem`?

Comment: If it helps the old code looked like this:

    _repository.Stub(x => x.SaveStatistics(null, null))
                .IgnoreArguments()
                .WhenCalled(mi => UpdateItem((Item)mi.Arguments.First(), (Statistics)mi.Arguments.Second()));

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it :) Reference came from this thread here with a similar issue. [Arg.Do()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587443/arg-do-is-not-firing-when-expected-in-a-when-do-for-void-method)

```
 _repository.When(
    x => x.SaveStatistics(Arg.Any<Item>(), statistics)).Do(
        call =>
            {
                itemUsed = call.Arg<Item>();
                UpdateItem(itemUsed, statistics);
            });
```

Comment: There is a bit more explanation of the `CallInfo` passed to that function here: http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/return-from-function/. In this case you could use `(Item) call[0]` or `call.Arg<Item>()`.